# getting wrong data from USB Communication in C#

Tags: c#, usb, microcontroller

I am using microcontroller to send data to computer. This is the code that I am using to get data:

```
    serialPort1.PortName = "COM13";
    serialPort1.BaudRate = 57600;
    serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
    serialPort1.Parity = Parity.Odd;
    serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One; 
    serialPort1.Open();

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        output += sp.ReadByte() + " ";
  }
```

But the problem is that I am getting wrong data, even sometimes I am missing one bytes. I am using "terminal" and it seems that I am sending data correctly with microcontroller but with c# I am getting wrong data.
Also is there any way to get the parameter of serial port automatically so that I dont need to set the parameters my self.

Comment: `sp.ReadByte` only reads one byte. I suspect that you want to call `sp.ReadExisting`, or perhaps one of the [Read overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.read(v=vs.110).aspx) to make sure that you read everything that was sent. You don't get a separate `DataReceived` event for every byte that's received.

Comment: Do the baud rates and port settings in your terminal match what you have specified here?